# Install plugin option missing on moodlecloud 3.9.2

Tags: moodle

I have the paid version for moodle cloud yet I don't see an option to install plugin. The version I'm working on is 3.9.2 I can only see the option plugin overview and install plugin is missing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As shown here: https://moodle.com/moodlecloud/#detailed-pricing

None of the Moodle Cloud options allow plugin or theme installation - if you need to be able to add plugins, then you need to either look at hosting the site yourself or contact a local [Moodle Partner](https://moodle.com/partners/) to discuss what hosting options they offer.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Moodle on your own cloud is cost effective and also you will get all the functionalities like plugin installation, easy to back up and upgrade etc. I can help if needed.